# How to combine the sum of one column based on multiple unique values of another column in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, data-manipulation

I'm looking to combine the sum of `Sales_volume($)` column, based on unique values in the `Store_name` column. Not sure if this is possible, but here is my DataFrame:

```
    Store_name  Sales_volume($) Date    
0   store 167   1.00               2019-06-03
1   store 167   4.00               2019-06-03
2   store 177   3.37               2019-06-03
3   store 177   2.14               2019-06-03
4   store 216   7.96               2019-06-03
5   store 216   1.99               2019-06-03
```

My desired output:

```
    Store_name  Sales_volume($) Date    
0   store 167   5.00               2019-06-03
1   store 177   5.51               2019-06-03
2   store 216   9.95               2019-06-03
```

Thanks!

Comment: Use: `df.groupby('Store_name').agg({'Sales_volume($)':'sum', 'Date':'first'}).reset_index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you want to group the data by `Store_name` and get a sum of the Sales for the store:
`df.groupby('Store_name').sum()`
or if you want to have a Sales for a store for every Date:
`df.groupby(['Store_name','Date']).sum()`